# How to disable cache in open cart CMS

Tags: php, caching, opencart

I used to set `$expire = 0;` in all cache.php files. Delete all from cache folder. Put `$this->cache->delete();` in some random files.  Use `Ctrl+F5` in my brouser. But cache still alive.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to just return `false` from the `cache->get` method:

**system/library/cache.php:**

```
public function get($key) {
    return false;
```

Comment: That did not work , in fact there was no change at all , its still cached..!!

Comment: If the system cache returns `false` then how can you possibly be retrieving cached data?  You must be using a third party cache extension.

Comment: Not sure about 3rd party cache extension, but no software should be overly complicated like open-cart, caching in more than one place with no option in the front end to turn it off. There might be several reasons to turn it off hence forcing a cache is ridiculous approach by opencart.

Comment: it's not forced and there is only one library for caching.  there's nothing complicated about it at all really.. it's only about 15 lines of code.  if you are having trouble understanding those functions that's no reason to slam the whole application.  I was only speculating you might be using an extension since my answer works and you were still having unrelated problems.  in all fairness, I didn't deserve a downvote here

Comment: With all due respect I beg to differ, if its not forced please tell me how to turn it caching off without touching the code from a layman's point of view? Well I will remove the downvote

Comment: @ClainDsilva - By default, the cache is only used for a very few internal functions like currency exchange rate, localisation settings and a few other things which the layman (or anyone else) would hardly ever have a reason to touch. MySQL also uses a query cache as part of the normal operation of it's database. There's no caching of html or any other dynamic page data which you'd ever find yourself needing to disable.

Answer (score 1):

Open up `system/library/cache.php` and comment these:

```
public function get($key) {
    // return $this->adaptor->get($key);
}

public function set($key, $value) {
    // return $this->adaptor->set($key, $value);
}
```

I know, it's very annoying. OpenCart really should implement an easier way to disable cache.

Comment: @BurakKalkan glad you found it useful, mate ;)

Answer (score 1):

*template_cache* takes the value from *developer_theme*. Do the following:

1. Go to oc_setting table (database)
2. Find (developer_theme) of the key column
3. Then change the value column to 0

Comment: Working but not perfect need to reload it two time

Comment: Don't forget to delete all files in .../storage/cache/

Answer (score -1):

I found it!! This worked for me... find vqmod.php file and before `$this->_filesModded[$sourcePath] = array('cached' => $changed);` Assign `$changed` to `false` like `$changed = false;` save and reload page.

Comment: vQmod is not part of OpenCart and not mentioned in this question so not relevant here.  Apart from that this is the wrong approach to disable vqcache which should be done by changing class property `$_devMode` to true: `private static $_devMode = true;` on line 17 of vqmod.php.

Comment: I'm giving a solution that worked for me, and a solution to a problem irrespective of approach...a better approach is nice though.

Comment: I'm not saying it didn't work for you, I'm saying you're solving a problem which is not what the OP asked about.  The vqcache has nothing to do with the opencart cache so it's off topic here.

Comment: Did you try the above solution?